# join() function onload page not working on mobile

Tags: agora.io

Join function works when click on join  button but not working on loading page my code for the click button is

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    setTimeout(function() {

     $( "#join" ).trigger( "click" );

    }, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issue is rooted in how most browsers are now handling video elements `auto` play functionality. ([chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), [Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/02/firefox-66-to-block-automatically-playing-audible-video-and-audio/),[safari](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)).

TLDR; The browsers will block `auto` play on any videos that have sound enabled unless the user interacts with the page via `click`. For this reason it works when you have `joinChannel` via `click`, it meets the criteria for a user initiated interaction with the page and so the browser allows the video to play.

This is the recommended behavior, as it ensures the user is ready to view the content. Take a look at Google Hangouts/Meet for a commercial product that implements this logic

There is another option, which is technically possible (but not recommended). You could start the video with the audio muted. The reason this isn't recommended is there is no telling if in the future browsers will block `auto` play functionality all together so this could break again.